# Getting "selectionSet is null" error when using apollo-link-state to save @client data

Tags: apollo

I'm not sure what this error exactly means. I get it when trying to call mutation on my local state

> message: "Network error: selectionSet is null" ​networkError:
>   TypeError: selectionSet is null

This is my code for apollo-link-state:

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
            cache,
            resolvers: {
                Mutation: {
                    setNavigationsState: (_:any, { path }:any, { cache }:any):any => {
                        cache.writeData(
                            {
                                navigationState: {
                                    __typename: 'NavigationState',
                                    path
                                }
                        });
                        return null;
                    },
                },
            },
            defaults: {
                navigationState: {
                    __typename: 'NavigationState',
                    path: "default",
                }
            },
        });
```

My call to mutate:

```
Apollo.client.mutate<FetchResult<ApolloQueryResult<any>>>({
            mutation:
            gql`
                mutation Test{
                    setNavigationsState(path:"newpath") @client{
                        path
                    }

                }
            `
        })
```

Graphql schema:

```
type RootMutation {
  setNavigationsState(path: String): NavigationState
}
type RootQuery {
  navigationState:NavigationState
}
type NavigationState {
  path:String!
}
```

It works fine when I try to query it:

```
let _test = Apollo.client.query<RootQuery>({
            query:
            gql`
                query TEST{
                        navigationState @client{
                            path
                        }

                }
            `
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe because navigationState is not at the root of cache, but in 'data':

```
cache.writeData({
  data: {
     navigationState: {
       __typename: 'NavigationState',
       path
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Error was really obscure and couldn't find anything about it in google. Hope this helps other people in future. Thank You !